# foreach прервать цикл и продолжить в другом месте

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3

У меня циклом foreach выводятся данные в шаблон в опред. поля как имя, описание, цена и т.д.

Мне надо вывести до 8 раз элементы из массива в тег с классом level_1 , а с 9 и до конца вывести все данные в другой класс level_2

Пример моего кода

```
<?php 
$i = 0;     
foreach($rows as $product){ // цикл выводит товары
    $i++; ?>       

   <?php if($i > 8){?>
   <div class="level_1">
   <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/vi_templay.php"); // подклю. шаблона с полям для вывода?> 
   </div>
    <?php  break; 
    }  else {
        continue;?>
   <div class="level_2">
   <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/vi_templay.php"); ?>
   </div>
    <?php }?>
```

Я знаю что код полное Г.. но уже не знал как решить, и использовал все. 
Мой код выводит товары с повторением, пример просто продукт_1 и его скажем 5 раз выводит.
А мне надо чтоб каждый шаг это новый товар выводило.

Поправка №1
На выходи должно выйти https://jsfiddle.net/wxv3qqc6/33/
в теги li у нас должно выйти так что тегс классом level_1  и level_2

Comment: так тебе надо в другом месте вывести или только циферку в level поменять?

Comment: кроме foreach есть еще for ;), Если я правильно понял ваше пожелание - может он подойдет вам больше

Comment: мне надо чтоб 8 товаров вывелось в тег level_1, должно выйти что 8 товаров обернуться в тег с классом level_1, а все что после 8 то в тег с классом level_2 и выйдет что остальная часть будут обернутые каждый элемент в тег с классом level_2

Comment: Я чет ассоциативный массив for вывести не не знаю просто

Comment: а каким местом он тут ассоциативный?

Comment: А то что в массиве $product есть ключ значение!

Comment: А по-твоему есть массивы, в которых нет ключа?

Comment: Тут как бы конкретно name : блабла, price: 100$ и т.д.

Comment: и все это в $rows? а если подумать?

Comment: @Pavel8289  кроме всего заметил некорректность в foreach, вы всегда будете начинать цикл с ключом 1, вам надо добавить $i++ в конце цикла, или же более красиво будет использовать foreach($rows as $key=>$product){ } и хорошо бы увидеть в расткрытом виде ваш объект

Comment: Вы это хотели глянуть https://codeshare.io/216wN3, var_dump($product) сделал

Comment: Вот так надо получить https://jsfiddle.net/wxv3qqc6/32/

Comment: У тебя по ссылке какая-то каша-малаша. список вообще не в этих дивах. Ты можешь что-то осмысленное и читабельное нарисовать?

Comment: Обновил, если значение есть в тегах. https://jsfiddle.net/wxv3qqc6/33/

Comment: Не спорю мб логика кода не верна, но надо как то сделать чтоб при выводи циклом вышло что один товар получает тег с классом 1 и другой 2 и все это в 2 li, потом след. li так же

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример, изучайте:

```
<?php

echo <<<CSS
    <style>
        .level_1 {
            color: green;
        }
        .level_2 {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
CSS;

$rows = [
    [
        'name' => '1. Василий',
        'description' => '1. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '1. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '2. Василий',
        'description' => '2. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '2. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '3. Василий',
        'description' => '3. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '3. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '4. Василий',
        'description' => '4. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '4. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '5. Василий',
        'description' => '5. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '5. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '6. Василий',
        'description' => '6. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '6. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '7. Василий',
        'description' => '7. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '7. Бесценный'
    ],
        [
        'name' => '8. Василий',
        'description' => '8. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '8. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '9. Василий',
        'description' => '9. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '9. Бесценный'
    ],

    [
        'name' => '10. Василий',
        'description' => '10. Тот, что Пупкин',
        'price' => '10. Бесценный'
    ]
];

foreach ($rows as $k => $product) {
    if ($k < 8) {
        echo '<div class="level_1">' . $product['name'] . ' ' . 
            $product['description'] . ' ' . $product['price'] . '<br /></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="level_2">' . $product['name'] . ' ' . 
            $product['description'] . ' ' . $product['price'] . '<br /></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично то что и искал!